# jQuery UI slider to show images on drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Need help on how to use this script to show images instead of values. I need 5 images to be shown when user drag handle. Like slideshow. Here is the slider code
http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps
Also need to make fade effect on image swap.
This is what i got so far:

```
$("#slider").slider({
animate: true,
min: 0,
max: 500,
step: 100,
slide: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.value == 100) {
        $('#green').hide();
    };
    if (ui.value == 200) {
        $('#green').hide();
        $('#red').show();
    };
     if (ui.value == 400) {
        $('#red').hide();
        $('#blue').show();
    };

    $("#hour").text(ui.value);
}  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LGMHP/182/
Help would be greatly appreciates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery offers a fadein fadeout that could easily let you do what you need. It's the equivalent of show and hide, but with a fade. http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

You can set animation duration and add a function on complete. So instead of the show and hide you have, you can do something like:

```
$('#green').hide('fast', function(){$('#red').show('slow');});
```

That said, you'll have a problem handling sliding from right to left. To handle all cases, maybe you should use classes. And to push a bit further and simplify, you could work with attributes. Like this:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    step: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {

        $('.showing').fadeOut(function(){$('[data-value='+ui.value+']').fadeIn().addClass('showing');}).removeClass('showing');

        $("#hour").text(ui.value);
    }
});
```

see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m67Lz3u7/